# Firebase cambia constantemente mis reglas de Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

el caso es sencillo:

- Tengo una app web, en cuya api rest (desarrollada en Express) habilito distintos endpoints, los cuales suelen consistir en funciones cuyo proposito es realizar operaciones sobre la base de datos de Firestore.
- Para poder tener acceso ilitimado en la api rest, lo que hago es mantener una sesión local (en la máquina que mantiene mi api rest activa) con unas credenciales de administrador (Por medio de Auth de Firebase), las cuales le permiten hacer todo tipo de operación.
- Lo anterior, en código se ve así:

```
let uid = "<admin-uid>";
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true}).then(() => {
  // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
  // next time a new one is issued.
});
```

- Para cumplir con lo anterior, configuré mis reglas así:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == "<admin-UID>";
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == "<admin-UID>";
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == "<admin-UID>";
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == "<admin-UID>";
    }     
  }
}
```

Si bien esto funciona durante un tiempo (generalmente menos de un día), eventualmente noto que Firebase las cambia automáticamente a las que venían cuando creé el proyecto, las cuales se ven algo así:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2019, 12, 6);
    }
  }
}
```

Las cuales, por la fecha en la cual se configura, no permite ninguna operación de escritura sobre la base de datos.
Qué reglas debo configurar para que queden permanentemente activas ?

Como información extra, todas las operaciones sobre Firestore se realizan en la api rest, nada en el frontend, por lo que debo configurar las reglas para que permitan todas las operaciones, en todas las colecciones, en ese código.

Comment: Creo que creaste tus reglas en modo de prueba, y por defecto firebase elimina las reglas que están modo de prueba después de haber transcurrido 24hrs. Desactiva el modo de prueba y vuelve a modificar tus reglas, y así ya no se borraran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado al comportamiento descrito en tu pregunta, lo más probable es que estés haciendo deploy de tus funciones y también incluyes el archivo destinado a la definición de tus reglas.

Lo anterior lo puedes verificar mediante 2 factores:

- Haciendo deploy usando `firebase deploy --only functions` y verificando que las reglas no hayan sido modificadas
- Revisando el archivo destinado a la definición de tus reglas y modificandolo directamente (sin usar la consola de firebase). Con esto asegurarás tener un respaldo de tus reglas, además de controlar sus modificaciones y usarlas en conjunto con la suite de emuladores para probar tu solución.

Comment: Era exactamente eso lo que me pasaba ! Muchas gracias :)